# New Activity does not start

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm new to programming, and trying to learn by following tutorials. I was following one tutorial and came across one problem and don't know to resolve it. 
In my MainActivity I'm trying to authenticate user by email and password. (works fine). After that HomenActivity supposed to start. Althought, for some reason it does not start. Unfortunatly I'm unable to understend why. If you could point me in the right direction it would be much apreciated.

Thank you all in advance.

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.firebase.ui.auth.AuthUI;

import com.firebase.ui.auth.IdpResponse;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;
import com.google.firebase.iid.InstanceIdResult;
import com.karumi.dexter.Dexter;
import com.karumi.dexter.PermissionToken;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionDeniedResponse;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionGrantedResponse;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionRequest;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.single.PermissionListener;
import com.raindevteam.aservicetracking.Model.User;
import com.raindevteam.aservicetracking.Utils.Common;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import io.paperdb.Paper;

import static java.sql.DriverManager.println;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseReference user_information;
    private static final int MY_REQUEST_CODE = 7117;
    List<AuthUI.IdpConfig> providers;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Paper.init(this);

        user_information = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Common.USER_INFORMATION);

        providers = Arrays.asList(
                new AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build(),
                new AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build()
                );

        Dexter.withActivity(this)
                .withPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                .withListener(new PermissionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPermissionGranted(PermissionGrantedResponse response) {
                showSignInOption();
            }

            @Override
            public void onPermissionDenied(PermissionDeniedResponse response) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You need to Accept permission",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(PermissionRequest permission, PermissionToken token) {

            }
        }).check();
    }

    private void showSignInOption(){
        startActivityForResult(
                AuthUI.getInstance()
                        .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                        .setAvailableProviders(providers)
                        .build(),MY_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode == MY_REQUEST_CODE){
            IdpResponse response = IdpResponse.fromResultIntent(data);
            if(requestCode == RESULT_OK){

                final FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

                user_information.orderByKey()
                        .equalTo(firebaseUser.getUid())
                        .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                                if(dataSnapshot.getValue() == null){
                                    if(!dataSnapshot.child(firebaseUser.getUid()).exists()){
                                        Common.loggedUser = new User(firebaseUser.getUid(),firebaseUser.getEmail());
                                        //add to database
                                        user_information.child(Common.loggedUser.getUid())
                                                .setValue(Common.loggedUser);
                                    }
                                }
                                //if user exists
                                else{
                                    Common.loggedUser = dataSnapshot.child(firebaseUser.getUid()).getValue(User.class);

                                }

                                Paper.book().write(Common.USER_UID_SAVE_KEY, Common.loggedUser.getUid());
                                updateToken(firebaseUser);

                                setupUI();


                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                            }
                        });
            }
        }
    }

    private void setupUI(){

        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, HomeActivity.class));
        finish();
    }

    private void updateToken(final FirebaseUser firebaseUser){
        final DatabaseReference tokens = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Common.TOKENS);

        FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(InstanceIdResult instanceIdResult) {
                tokens.child(firebaseUser.getUid()).setValue(instanceIdResult.getToken());

            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Error"+e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

No error messages displayed.

Comment: can you add the HomeActivity code

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think your setupUI() is not running try printing Log.e . Check if it is working or not.

Answer (score 0):

Would you try that?

```
private void setupUI(){

    startActivity(new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class));
    finish();
}
```